# 3D Vector Rotation of Point Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, rotation, rotational-kinematics

Triangle defined by points **OA**, **OB** and **OC** : (-**i**,3 **j**,-4 **k**), (**i**,2 **j**,2 **k**) and (3 **i**,7 **j**,- **k**) where **i**, **j**, **k** are unit vectors along x,y,z axis. Point mass is placed at **OA**. Triangle rotates with angular velocity **ω** about **BC** axis. Calculate linear velocity of mass as it passes **OA**.

My Work:
$$v=\omega \times r $$
Does **r** have to be the vector perpendicular to **BC** to the point **OA** or can it be any vector from the line **BC** to **OA**??? If so can you explain? I know the answer as my tutor told me I got it right but I didn't need to find the vector perpendicular to **BC** and I forgot to ask why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be any vector from **BC** to **OA**.

Let's assume that $r$ is the vector perpendicular to **BC** to the point **OA**.  Any vector from **BC** to **OA** (whether or not it is perpendicular to **BC**) has the form $r + s$, where $s$ is some vector parallel to **BC**.  Of course, you've told us that $\omega$ is also parallel to **BC**, so we could also write that as $r+\alpha\, \omega$, for some number $\alpha$.  So let's take the cross product:
\begin{equation}
\omega \times (r+\alpha\, \omega) = \omega \times r + \omega \times (\alpha\, \omega) = \omega \times r + \alpha\, \omega \times \omega = \omega \times r~,
\end{equation}
since $\omega \times \omega = 0$.  So $\omega$ cross any vector from **BC** to **OA** will equal $\omega$ cross the perpendicular vector.  So you don't need to specifically find the perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \vec{v}_A = \vec{v}_B + \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{r}_A -\vec{r}_B ) $$

with $\vec{v}_B =0$.

Any components of $(\vec{r}_A -\vec{r}_B )$ along $\vec{\omega}$ cancel out, so you don't have to worry about finding the perpendicular.